# redirect to another web project sending parameters

Tags: jsf, cas

I am redirecting to another project in the same workspace using the following code:

```
String urlVolver = "https://localhost:8443/wap/project2/registro/registrarProyect2.page?idRegistro=1648&control=gestionarGestionarRegistro";
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.getExternalContext().redirect(urlVolver);
```

When i redirect to the other project and i don't send parameters it works, but when i try to send parameters to the controller of that view i get the following exception

Error processing request

```
Context Path:
/wap/project2

Servlet Path:
/registro/registrarProyect2.page

Path Info:
null

Query String:
idRegistro=1648&control=gestionarGestionarRegistro

Stack Trace
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
org.jasig.cas.client.util.URIBuilder.addParameter(URIBuilder.java:402)
org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.constructServiceUrl(CommonUtils.java:310)
org.jasig.cas.client.util.AbstractCasFilter.constructServiceUrl(AbstractCasFilter.java:104)
org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:159)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:97)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: That does not look like an exception. Can you post the whole Exception? With parts of the stacktrace perhaps?

Comment: Ok, this is all the exception

Comment: Seems like you are using a CAS service for authentication between Projects? I guess the problem is, the CAS service uses an unmodifiable list and as you add parameters to the URL, CAS is trying to add them to that list?

Comment: We are using CAS for authentication between Projects, Any idea about how to do this with CAS?

Comment: I don't know anyhting about CAS, sorry. But I searched a little bit a saw someone saying something about SAML for GET parameters. Perhaps this gives you another search hint.

Answer (score 0):

We find a solution that, i think is not the most recommendable, but it works, the CAS configuration could not be modified because multiple aplications are using it, and this configuration not depends from our team.

Another behavior that i forgot to mention, is that when i load first the page  https://localhost:8443/wap/project2/registro/registrarProyect2.page and after  make the redirection with parameters the page has not problem to load.

So, we load the page in an iframe hidden with the navigation case.

```
 <div id="map" style="display:block; visibility:hidden"> 
    <iframe src="/registro/registrarProyect2">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

And after load this iframe we can redirect to the page with parameters.